# Lag compensation of projectile shooting game

Tags: networking, actionscript-3, game-mechanics

I'm thinking about an algorithm for firing projectiles with lag compensation. Now I did find only one descent solution:

1. Player hits fire button.
2. Client sends input "fire".
3. Client waits for server response.
4. Server generates bullet then sends response to client.
5. Client recieves response and finally fires projectile.

Is this solution only "trueway"? I find it the only one that can be fair to all of the clients. Valve in this case, doesn't compensate lag from rocket shots. I am feeling that I will not compensate it, too. I think that with today's bandwidth I can close my eyes on this problem, because I don't see any solutions with fair logic. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention bullets...

1. player hits fire
2. player immediately draws something
3. client sends command to server
4. server gets fire command
5. server calculates the results, hit or miss
6. server sends result to player
7. player applies the result from the server
8. player draws something to show the result

There is no physical "bullet" flying around, just a phantom drawn locally.  You cannot wait 200msec for for server responses or your game will feel sluggish.

Rockets are a totally different subject: they are expected to have an "ignition time" before flying off, they move slowly, they have an area-effect when they hit, some have a small AI guiding them during flight.  Bullets are not rocket science.

Comment: I need projectiles with life time and flying time, and i will not have rockets, players will shoot projectiles, like small fireballs, frozen arrows, etc. How i have to manage networking with projectiles?

Comment: Actually not all games use this approach. The sluggish feel is not true for every FPS. Unreal Tournament 2004 and 3 waits for the server respond before shooting.  Not only for rockets, but every weapon, including shock rifle.

Comment: Yeah i feel like i just dont need to make any prediction system for projectiles and spells, just wait for server response

Comment: You need prediction if there is latency.  Otherwise, you're asking for a laggy game.  There is nothing worse than hitting the "fire" button, and having a delay.  Keep in mind that a 1/4 second delay is unacceptable, even if it seems like a very quick amount of time.

Comment: And how i need to predict flying projectile and be fair to players?

Comment: http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/what-every-programmer-needs-to-know-about-game-networking/ is the usual link for basic ideas.  From there is also a link to Unreal networking technology, which is a good reference.  I think that it would be very easy to try a version where the server controls all inputs and then later add on more advanced techniques like prediction - until you actually play you won't really know how your game feels.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, i'll read how unreal implemented thier networking

Comment: Ok, i read Unreal doc, but i cant understand. If client predicts projectile, it quiet big chance to make a mistake(miss or hit). So this approach is designed for more responsibility but less accurate?

Comment: It's up to the player to learn how to aim in traditional shooters so the accuracy depends entirely on what the player does.  In a standard RPG or MMO setting the chance to hit is figured out by the rules and then the projectiles are made to act like they hit or miss based on the result.  There are middle ground designs that use "target lock" or auto-targeting to help with aim, too, mainly for consoles where you don't have good fine control like with a mouse.  It all depends on how you want your game to play.

Comment: I understood it. I dont understand when 1 player with, say ping 200 ms shoot ar player with 50 ping, projectile starts at client(200ms)       in predictable way, fly and finally detect hit. Server take command to shoot rewinds world to 200 ms to past, spawn projectile, simulate world with projectile and then detect hit to, but for 50 ping player it will be some kind of magic, he will see that projectile spawned from nowhere near him and killed him. That what i found not fair.

Comment: Timing is the main reason big games like to point people to local servers to use, at least everyone will have relatively similar pings and then the not-fair stuff evens out.  Remember, you can do that to him but HE can do that to YOU too =)  Mostly little glitches in timing get lost in the fun of playing so it's OK.